# Maven javadoc + custom doclet

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

How can i specify the doclect artifact when calling mvn from command line

```
mvn clean install javadoc:javadoc -Ddoclet=my.Doclet -DdocletArtifact=????
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add something like this to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <doclet>my.doclet</doclet>
      <docletArtifact>
        <groupId>my.artifact.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>my.artifact.id</artifactId>
        <version>my.artifact.version</version>
      </docletArtifact>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This is also documented in detail in section [Using Alternate Doclet](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/alternate-doclet.html) of the [Apache Maven Javadoc Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) documentation.

You cannot simply specify these parameters from the command line, but using a [Build Profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) may help you selecting the configuration you want to have.

Comment: so there is no possibility without touching the pom