# How to use different doclets in one project? (maven plugin javadoc)

Tags: java, maven, markdown, javadoc, doclet

In a codebase that is documented in JavaDoc currently we'd like to transition to a Markdown-based documentation.

There exist doclets to parse Markdown documentation comments.

However, it is not feasible to rewrite all doc comments in an enterprise project all at once.

- Is there a way to start and convert one doc comment at a time and still get an aggregate API documenatation? (I'd imagine, if there is, it would work via an annotation or a docstring tag which acts as a switch between the doclets to use).
- If there exists one, what is the maven configuration?

Potentially related questions:

- [Maven javadoc + custom doclet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189441/maven-javadoc-custom-doclet)
- [Maven: Dependency-driven javadoc aggregation and custom doclet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443363/maven-dependency-driven-javadoc-aggregation-and-custom-doclet)